# Getting "ValidationError: 1 validation error for VectorstoreIndexCreator embedding"

Tags: python, machine-learning, large-language-model, openaiembeddings

I am trying to build a pdf chat bot where you upload a pdf and ask questions related to you pdf. For this, I was thinking of a RAG based application . So i wanted to create vector embeddings of my input pdf but when i do this,

```
from llama_index.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbedding
embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbedding(model_name="BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5")
index_creator = VectorstoreIndexCreator(
    vectorstore_cls = Cassandra,
    embedding = embed_model,
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
        chunk_size = 400,
        chunk_overlap = 30
    ),

    vectorstore_kwargs={
        'session': session,
        'keyspace': keyspace,
        'table_name': table_name
    }
)
```

I am getting validation error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-b83dc7fd1587> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 keyspace = "pdf_qa_name"
      3 
----> 4 index_creator = VectorstoreIndexCreator(
      5     vectorstore_cls = Cassandra,
      6     embedding = embed_model,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py in __init__(__pydantic_self__, **data)
    339         values, fields_set, validation_error = validate_model(__pydantic_self__.__class__, data)
    340         if validation_error:
--> 341             raise validation_error
    342         try:
    343             object_setattr(__pydantic_self__, '__dict__', values)

ValidationError: 1 validation error for VectorstoreIndexCreator
embedding
  instance of Embeddings expected (type=type_error.arbitrary_type; expected_arbitrary_type=Embeddings)
```

Any idea?

Tried 2 different models(Jina and BAAI/bge). The error is not going. I am using open ai gpt 3.5 api.